# Blender 2.8 GPU Cycles Compatibility .. NVidia Quadro M1000M ... Windows 10

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

Recently Blender 2.8 ... Windows 10.

Cycles Rendering rejected a NVidia 670M Mobile Card in Laptop 01.  Probably based on NVidia Compute Capability.

Should I expect a NVidia Quadro M1000M to be Blender 2.8 compatible?. Laptop 02 which is not currently in my possession.

Two different laptops.

I have never owned a Quadro GPU.  Your general comments are welcome.  Does anyone have experience with this exact video card?

Answer (score 1):

By coincidence, today I did a render using Blender 2.8 on a laptop with a Quadro M1000M card. No issues there, worked fine!

Quadro cards seem to be made for rendering and GFX design, so a good choice. A good read: https://www.engineering.com/DesignSoftware/DesignSoftwareArticles/ArticleID/18630/Whats-the-Difference-Between-GeForce-and-Quadro-Graphics-Cards.aspx.

Regarding the number of tiles, here are the answers:

- Cycles only uses 1 tile per GPU (does not apply to CPU);
- The number of tiles are dictated by available logical cores (or
  threads);
- Blender seems to use a maximum of 8 tiles;

So what brought me on the wrong track earlier: I thought I was seeing 4 tiles for the quadro and 4 for the CPU, but actually it was 1 tile for the quadro (as expected) and the remaining 7 tiles for the CPU (being a quadcore with hyperthreading = 8 logical cores (or threads) in total).
In retrospective to my desktop, where I also have a quad core CPU with hyperthreading (8 threads), but also 4 GPU's (2x 1070 TI's + 2x 970) = 8 tiles total.

Comment: Please don't use the answers section to ask questions.

Comment: It's relative to the answer, so I would hardly call this a question.